# How to download information?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

Currently, I have the following that downloads all files under an AWS (Amazon Web Services) S3 bucket.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you trying to do this with boto3?  Or with the original boto library?  You code snippet references both.  Also, you code snippet doesn't define s3client so I can't tell what that is.

Comment: @garnaat Overlooked it. With boto3 as shown in code provided. Defined `awsclient`. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are no such a limits in boto3 lib. If amazon would decided to put a limit , your application would exited with an error from amazon. I would imagine something similar to `boto3.exceptions.ClientError("BlahBlahLimitError .....")` .  Take a look at some background processes or something that times out your python process on the host. Also make sure to use pagination, to make multiple requests to AWS

Comment: The ``list_objects_v2`` method of the S3 client does not handle pagination automatically.  So, you are getting a single page of results.  Use the resource approach I show below to get automatic pagination.

Comment: @Vor Appreciate the response! If you can provide some ways on what to check for in the background processes, would really appreciate it. Also, how would I make sure to use pagination? Thank you in advance

Comment: @garnaat Got it but how can I retrieve metadata with the resource approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in boto3, you could do something like this:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
for object_summary in bucket.objects.all():
    print(object_summary.key)
    print(object_summary.last_modified)
```

In this case boto3 will handle all pagination so you won't be limited to only the first page of results.

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've actually compared it to the actual bucket on the AWS console, and it does go through a few pages, yet it stops at around 550~ files. I even made the attempt with `MaxKeys = 2000`, even though the default is 1000, and yet the program still completes at around 550~ when there is more to download. What other possibly could be an issue?

Comment: Yes, I did and it does list all the object names. Is it possible to do it with `list_objects_v2`? Because I'd like to retrieve the object's metadata as well, which `list_objects_v2` provides.

Comment: It's possible but you have to handle the pagination yourself.  That would involve looking for a ``ContinuationToken`` in the response and then making another request to ``list_objects_v2`` passing that ``ContinuationToken`` in the request. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: Each of the objects returned by the resource collection is an instance of an ``ObjectSummary`` class as described here (https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#objectsummary).  You should be able to find all of the same data for each object as that returned by ``list_objects_v2``.

Comment: Got it. Do you mind providing how to retrieve metadata? Can't seem to locate how to obtain specific object properties via object['LastModified'], object['Key'] for example for `list_objects_v2`.

Comment: Those are available as attributes of the ``ObjectSummary`` object.  I have updated the code snippet above to show how you can access those two specific values.  For others, refer to the docs of ``ObjectSummary`` provided above.

Answer (score 0):

From Documentation: 
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=s3#S3.Client.list_objects_v2
*Returns some or all (up to 1000) of the objects in a bucket.*

```
response = client.list_objects_v2(
Bucket='string',
Delimiter='string',
EncodingType='url',
MaxKeys=123,
Prefix='string',
ContinuationToken='string',
FetchOwner=True|False,
StartAfter='string',
RequestPayer='requester'
```

)

**MaxKeys (integer) -- Sets the maximum number of keys returned in the response. The response might contain fewer keys but will never contain more.**

Do you know how many objects do you have in s3?

Comment: Appreciate your response! Under a bucket, there are multiple folders, and under each folder there are the downloadable files. So to clarify, does each folder represent an object, or each downloadable file? Also, would I just need to define the `response = client.list_objects_v2(...)` somewhere at the time, and run the provided code? By default, what are `MaxKeys` set to?

Comment: In s3 each file is an object.

Comment: http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--what-is-object-introduction.html

Comment: It is set to 1000

Comment: Thought so. That's odd then, because the total number of files I've downloaded are only around 550~. Is the max only applied to per program run? Or during certain actual time period? E.g.: Like within 1 hour, I can only download up to 1000 with default MaxKeys.

Comment: Just checking in to see if you've checked my last comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Limitation:  boto3 list_object() and list_object_v2() will return maximum 1000 keys. To continue get object, you need to make use of "ContinuationToken" parameter.  boto3.s3.resource.objects.all()  will generate an iterator, currently there is no known limit.

However, you must know this :

1. Downloading from S3 to your local system from the internet WILL cost you, i.e. 0.09/GB. If you need frequently process on such files, maybe you should run your download inside EC2 or use lambda to do the post-processing.
2. same region S3 data to EC2 download is free. you can run test massive download proof (e.g. say 100GB+  ) without worry about the bill.  You just pay EC2 instance.
3. Downloading performance/continuity of session from s3 to your local intranet , are subject to your local internet connectivity setup. This can be restriction in your own firewall policies, your router, ISP, etc

Comment: Appreciate the insight! Do you mind showing how to use "ContinuationToken" parameter? Thank you!